# Artifactory plugin does not deploy artifacts in Jenkins without reason

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I'm using the artifactory plugin 2.16.1 in jenkins in my pipeline
At a run I got:

```
[main] WARN org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Artifactory Build Info Recorder: unstable build, artifacts will not be deployed...
[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Artifactory Build Info Recorder: publish build info set to false, build info will not be published...
```

while everything is succesful and nothing failed, but the artifacts aren't deployed

A bit later a second run without any change works and artifacts are deployed. What could be the issue? I don't know what could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

The log is stating the following

```
 [main] WARN org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper - Artifactory Build Info Recorder: unstable build, artifacts will not be deployed...
```

**i.e.  unstable build, artifacts will not be deployed**

In the Artifactory configuration section,
Check(tick) the Deploy even if the build is unstable

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Cant able to deploy in multi module gradle projects using build artifactorypublish task. Added the publish default blocks in build.gradle of root. But still only the parent module artifact is getting uploading and sub modules its not uploading.